# Needing assistance with mysql count queries

Tags: sql, count, mariadb

I have done several searches, I'm afraid I don't know how to use the right words to get a successful answer to my question. Maybe someone can help guide me in the right direction. Here's what I got..

I can run this query

```
SELECT GeoCode, Package 
FROM `customers` 
WHERE GeoCode LIKE '2%' AND Package LIKE 'R%' 
ORDER BY GeoCode ASC, Package ASC;
```

and I get this as a result:

[image]

What i need to do next is get a count of each package within a certain geocode.. 
So for example.. I need a result to show that there are 3 'R4M/2M' within the 20043020300 Geocode, 1 'R2M/1M' within the 20043020300 Geocode and so forth..

Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` should do the job:

```
SELECT geocode, package, COUNT(package)
FROM `customers` 
WHERE GeoCode LIKE '2%' AND Package LIKE 'R%'
GROUP BY geocode, package
ORDER BY GeoCode ASC, Package ASC;
```

It might be a good idea to consult a tutorial or the MySQL documentation relating to group by queries, if you're unsure of some of the basic concepts like this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have however tried this and i get this error ...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE GeoCode LIKE '2%' AND Package LIKE 'R%'
ORDER BY GeoCode ASC, Package ASC
' at line 4

Comment: The results i get from my first query are perfect and in the order I need them. Do you think I should maybe create a temp table from those results and then run another query of some kind against that table to get the results im looking for? Or maybe use a subquery? I have read through several tutorials, i just cant seem to get it working.. at this point i have no more than 3 days of experience and am on my own

Comment: No, a group by query should work. Not quite sure why you have a syntax error. Let me check.

Comment: ah ok sorry the where clause has to go before the group by clause. Should have checked the manual myself! See the amended answer, try it now

Comment: No problem...remember if the answer has helped you, please mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the question so that it turns green) - thanks :-)